# How to make a function that never pick twice the same image

Tags: java, android, random

I'm trying to make a function that generate random images, but never twice and it goes until there are no images left.

In my case, there are 15 image files in drawable, and I want them to all be shown but without repeating.

```
package com.example.commander;


import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {





final Random rnd = new Random();
ImageView img = null;
Button btnRandom = null;






@Override
protected void onCreate(
    final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
    btnRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRandom);
}



protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
            );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}





ArrayList<Integer> imageId = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 public void clickHandler(final View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {



        case R.id.btnRandom:
            {
                if (!btnRandom.isEnabled())
                {
                    return;
                }


               int indeks = rnd.nextInt(14);


                final String str = "img_" + indeks;
                img.setImageDrawable
                (
                    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                        getApplicationContext())));




            }}}









@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

public void goBack(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

insert all image id to one list, use AndroidWarriors answer for generate one random number, get that image and remove from list, call more time until size of your list became 0

you can use following code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> imageId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// insert your id here
```

then:

```
  int index ;
     while (imageId.size() > 0)
     {
      index =  randomInt(0 , imageId.size());


     /// do what you want with this index

       imageId.remove(index);

     }
```

and `randomInt`

```
public int randomInt(int min, int max) {

    Random randNumber = new Random();

    int randomNumber = randNumber.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have tried your solution but I can't get it to work. I really don't know what am I doing wrong.

I've updated my first post with complete code that I am using.
If you would be so kind to explain me on my code because I don't know what code to put where (still learning).

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: you don't use this at all, read my answer again and do that, you don't remove from your list, and you always generate random number between 0 - 14

Comment: Can you check my first post and explain me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: first of all you must put all index that you have to one list, then you need use  `indeks =  randomInt(0 , imageId.size());` instead of `int indeks = rnd.nextInt(14);` and after setting to imageView you need remove that index from list.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the images by generating random number within a range

```
public int randomInt(int min, int max) {

    Random randNumber = new Random();

    int randomNumber = randNumber.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNumber;
}
```

Also maintain an `ArrayList` of integers as a class member variable and insert the int value that you receive from the function. While setting the image check whether that int returned exists in the array. If yes then again call the function, if no then set the image and finally when the length of array becomes 15 stop executing your code.

Comment: **but never twice and it goes until there are no images left.**